# Starting an application as a scheduled task does not work

Tags: command-line, sudo, reboot, schedule, rtorrent

I have a seedbox under an Ubuntu desktop server.

I can run rtorrent correctly but if I restart the server I need to relaunch rtorrent with this command:

```
sudo -i
screen -fa -d -m rtorrent
```

I would like use Scheduled Task, so I add at reboot the command `screen -fa -d -m rtorrent`, but that doesn't work... Maybe because I'm not using the `sudo -i` before the command...

How can I launch this command automatically when the server reboots?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your command needs root, but if it does, use `cron`:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add a line to `root`'s `crontab`:

```
@reboot screen -fa -d -m rtorrent
```